# Getting an empty modal when starting a bounty

Tags: bug, design, bounty

When starting a bounty of 50, I was getting the following result during 2 or more times of trying - empty modal / pop-up.

[image: Empty modal when starting bounty]

This made it impossible to finish giving a bounty to the question.

What I've done to fix it and start the bounty was to click in a higher bounty amount (100) and before really starting it, closed that modal / pop-up, then it went back to the original 50. Then the problem was solved.

Comment: Given this doesn't seem to be wide-spread (or would have been mentioned before). 
Could this be browser specific?  What browser are you using?  Is it specific to the dark theme?

Comment: @psubee2003 using Google Chrome.

Comment: It [seems fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al57v.png) in dark mode with Chrome Desktop 80.0.3987.106 on Windows 10 (2004).

Comment: @WaiHaLee Could it be related to me having an active bonus of 500? Or that I was starting a bonus before the time (this one I don't think so because it showed I was able to and then some moments after allowed)?

Comment: I don't know - maybe? I don't really want to award a bounty of 500 to test it. Hopefully a Stack Exchange developer will see this and figure out what the deal is. BTW have you tried using another browser?

Comment: @WaiHaLee No i didn't try with another browser because after that change in the procedure it started to work and I was able to award the bounty. Now when I test it it works